# JPA mapping table could not delete

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-boot, mariadb

I have entity Account, Role, AccountRole.

```
@Entity
public class Account {
    @Id
    private String loingId;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String email;
    private boolean enable;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "account", orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<AccountRole> accountRoles = new ArrayList<>();

    public String getLoingId() {
        return loingId;
    }
    public void setLoingId(String loingId) {
        this.loingId = loingId;
    }
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }
    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
    public boolean isEnable() {
        return enable;
    }
    public void setEnable(boolean enable) {
        this.enable = enable;
    }
    public List<AccountRole> getAccountRoles() {
        return accountRoles;
    }
    public void setAccountRoles(List<AccountRole> accountRoles) {
        this.accountRoles = accountRoles;
    }
    public void addAccountRoles(AccountRole accountRoles) {
        if (this.accountRoles == null){
            this.accountRoles = new ArrayList<>();
        }
        this.accountRoles.add(accountRoles);
        accountRoles.setAccount(this);
    }
    public void removeAccountRoles(){
        this.accountRoles = null;
    }
}

@Entity
public class Role {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String description;
    private boolean enable;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "role")
    private List<AccountRole> accountRoles = new ArrayList<>();

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
    public boolean isEnable() {
        return enable;
    }
    public void setEnable(boolean enable) {
        this.enable = enable;
    }
    public List<AccountRole> getAccountRoles() {
        return accountRoles;
    }
    public void setAccountRoles(List<AccountRole> accountRoles) {
        this.accountRoles = accountRoles;
    }
}


@Entity
public class AccountRole implements Serializable{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "account_id")
    private Account account;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "role_id")
    private Role role;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public Account getAccount() {
        return account;
    }
    public void setAccount(Account account) {
        this.account = account;
    }
    public Role getRole() {
        return role;
    }
    public void setRole(Role role) {
        this.role = role;
    }
}
```

To create account with role is OK.
There is a problem in update.

I want to delete the existing Role and only add the changed Role when the Role of the Account is changed. However, existing data is not deleted from the AccoutRole table.

How can I solve the problem?

springBootVersion = '1.5.3.RELEASE'

java 1.8

gradle dependencies

```
dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')

    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')

    runtime ('org.mariadb.jdbc:mariadb-java-client')
}
```

Comment: how do you want to delete/update the data?

Comment: How do you make the change to the role? Could you provide a sample for that?

Comment: @XtremeBaumer   
If the Role changes, I want to delete the existing Role and add a new Role.

Comment: @Brian  `public void update(Account account, Role role) {
        if (role != null){
            AccountRole accountRole = new AccountRole();
            accountRole.setAccount(account);
            accountRole.setRole(role);

            account.getAccountRoles().remove(account.getAccountRoles());

            account.getAccountRoles().add(accountRole);
            accountRoleRepository.save(accountRole);
        }else{
            accountRepository.save(account);
        }
    }`

Comment: why not just update it?

Answer (score 0):

A couple of ideas:

#### Thought 1: Try using cascade

Yes, JPA 2.0 should handle this with `orphanRemoval = true`, but let's just see if that works. I think that it is not because you aren't creating an orphan here. The mapping is still "valid" from a relational perspective.

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "account", cascade = CascadeType.ALL) // or CascadeType.REMOVE
private List<AccountRole> accountRoles = new ArrayList<>();
```

#### Thought 2: Try setting the account roles to an empty hashmap instead first:

```
account.setAccountRoles(new HashMap<AccountRole>());
account.getAccountRoles().add(accountRole);;
```

Comment: I solved this problem. I write @Transactional my testcase. So insert is rollback.....